# Can we build $\beth_2$ number of balls from one balls according Banach Tarski theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

It has been shown that one may create $\beth_1$ balls from one ball:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Banach%E2%80%93Tarski_paradox#Obtaining_infinitely_many_balls_from_one
but is it true to any bet number? supposedly no, as there are not enough points in the Euclidean to embed the whole sphere, but still, this is not a formal claim. One might claim that we show there cannot be $\beth_2$ balls according to Schröder–Bernstein theorem, but still I might miss something.

Comment: What is $2\beth$? Do you mean $\beth_2 = 2^{2^{\aleph_0}}$?

Comment: Also, I don't know what you mean by "but still, this is not a formal claim". The Banach Tarski theorem takes place in $\mathbb{R}^3$, which has cardinality $2^{\aleph_0}$. So of course you can't embed more than $2^{\aleph_0}$ balls in $\mathbb{R}^3$. What's not formal about this argument?

Comment: You can multiply any two cardinals.

Comment: @AlexKruckman yes exactly.

Comment: @AlexKruckman it's true intuitively, but why can't we balls that fits the same place?

Comment: @thecounterexample If you meant $\beth_2$, then the answer is no since we cannot divide $\mathbb{R}$ into more than $\beth_1$ pieces.

Comment: Balls with the same radius and center point are equal.

Comment: yeah but allegedly, no one said that all the balls must be unique.

Comment: @AsafKaragila why? why can't we just take 2 balls and put them in the same place?

Comment: A ball is a set of points in the space. Two sets with the same elements (or points, in this case) are equal. Your argument is essentially saying that the Banach–Tarski paradox is just too much work: take the unit ball, now give it two names, and you have two balls!

Comment: @AsafKaragila שלום מישראל =)

Comment: @AsafKaragila so we define a ball to be different from other ball if one has a point that the other not?

Comment: Yes, two balls will have a point which belongs to the one but not the other. In the case of balls we can uniquely determine a ball by its center point and the radius, as I mentioned. Since you're concerned with balls of radius $1$ (or some other fixed radius), then we only have the center point to work with. But even if you allow the radius to vary, there are only $\beth_1$ different pairs of (point,radius) anyway.

Comment: The question of where you put all the divided balls with all pairs distinct is moot to me. That is just a matter of producing a bigger space to put them in. I.e. - giving each a unique label.

Answer (score 1):

The original ball you are dividing up consists of $\beth_1$ points. Therefore it is impossible to divide it into more than $\beth_1$ pairwise-disjoint sets, no matter how those sets are shaped geometrically.